# Google sheets copy whole sheet to another

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google spreadsheet that includes a couple of sheets that are dynamically maintained from a variety of sources.  Call them Dynamic_data1 and Dynamic_data2.

For each of these dynamic sheets there is a companion static sheet.  Let's call them Static_data1 and Static_data2.

I have a periodic need do the following for these two pairs of sheets, which I have been doing manually:

1. Delete the entire contents of Static_data1
2. Copy the entire contents of Dynamic_data1
3. "paste special/paste values only" the values from Dynamic_data1 into Static_data1

Then repeat the process for Dynamic_data2/Static_data2

It's always the whole sheet, regardless of the number of rows or columns present.

Doing this manually works fine, but I find I have the need to automate it.  I've done a little scripting, not much, so I am no expert.

I can't help but think this should be a simple job for a script.  However, my inept googling has not located something I can adapt.  I'd be grateful for advice.

Comment: Take a look at this;https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function copyAll() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();//Spreadsheet with spreadsheet id's
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('FromToList');//sheet with spreadsheet id's
  const idA=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().map((r)=>{
    return {from:r[0],to:r[1]};//FromToList is a sheet with from id's in columnA and to id's in columnB
  });//tested down to here the rest is up to you.  I recommend not unleashing this on real spreadsheets until after you have thoroughly tested it.
  idA.forEach(obj=>{
    let fss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(obj.from);//from Spreadsheet
    let fshts=fss.getSheets();//from sheets
    let tss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(obj.to);//to Spreadsheet
    let tshts=tss.getSheets();//to sheets
    fshts.forEach(fsh=>{
      fsh.copyTo(tss);//copy all from sheets to to spreadsheet
    });
    tshts.forEach(tsh=>{
      tss.deleteSheet(tsh);//delete all original to sheets in to spreadsheet
    });
  });
}
```

Note: function has not be tested